# Webpack - How do I configure Webpack to bundle global and modularized CSS differently?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 project and using Webpack 2 for bundling code and assets. The Angular application uses Bootstrap and a styles.css containing some global styles across the board.

Furthermore the Angular components themselves have their own style sheets in seperate .css files. See the below file structure as an example:

```
app/index.html
app/styles.css
app/component/component.js
app/component/component.html
app/component/component.css
```

At the moment, Webpack takes all of these files both .css and .js and bundles them together, so I have the following output (CSS combined into javascript):

```
dist/index.html
dist/js/app.bundle.js
```

The problem I have mainly is that this creates a FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content) - From my understanding the way to fix it is changing the code split for CSS to output CSS into its own file so it can be asynchronously loaded by the browser - using the Extract-Text-Webpack-Plugin.

This works great except using this method I'm left with another problem. I lose the ability to have modular CSS that Angular provided through the *component.css* files...

***So I have the following 2 questions:***

1.) How do I configure Webpack to just extract Bootstrap and my styles.css into e.g. "dist/styles.css" but bundle the rest of the "non-global" css files as part of the javascript bundles that Webpack creates me?

2.) Is it possible to inject this extracted CSS into the HEAD section of index.html just like the bundles are being injected through HTML-webpack-plugin?

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    template: 'ngApp/index.html'
})
```

*(This is so I don't have to hard-code the href in  to point to the output path that could potentially change if someone alters the Webpack config.)*

My current solution to this problem was to use copy-webpack-plugin to move *bootstrap.min.css* and *styles.css* to *dist* and use a hard-coded link in index.html - But I do not like that setup. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I tried to answer a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698124/webpack-bundle-all-css-and-load-first/43972645#43972645).

I am also looking for a better solution, but this one works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is still relevant:
I've managed to at find a solution to your first question, as I was trying to build an Angular 4 frontend for a Spring Boot application and faced the exact same problem. Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {};

    /**
     * Devtool
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
     */
    if (isProd) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    }
    else {
        config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    }

    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    config.entry = {
        'polyfills': './src/main/frontend/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/main/frontend/vendor.ts',
        'style': './src/main/frontend/style/global.scss',   // global styles
        'app': './src/main/frontend/main.ts'                // angular app
    };

    /**
     * Output
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    config.output = {
        path: root('src/main/webapp'),
        publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    };

    /**
     * Resolve
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    config.resolve = {
        // only discover files that have those extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    };

    /**
     * Loaders
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
     * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
     */
    config.module = {
        rules: [

            // Support for .ts files.
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            },

            // copy those assets to output
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]?'
            },

            // Support for *.json files.
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },

            // build global css bundle from src/main/frontend/style/global.css
            {
                test: /global\.(css|scss)/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
            },

            // all css required in src/main/frontend files will be merged in js files
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
                exclude: [/global\.(css|scss)/]
            },

            // support for .html as raw text
            // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    };

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
     */
    config.plugins = [
        // Define env variables to help with builds
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // Environment helpers
            'process.env': {
                ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),


        // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            root('./src/main/frontend') // location of your src
        ),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                /**
                 * PostCSS
                 * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
                 * Add vendor prefixes to your css
                 */
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: ['last 2 version']
                    })
                ]
            }
        }),

        // Generate common chunks if necessary
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        // Extract css files
        // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
        // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].min.css'
        })
    ];

    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
            // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: {keep_fnames: true}}),


            // optimize CSS assets
            // Reference: https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
                cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    discardComments:
                        {
                            removeAll: true
                        }
                },
                canPrint: true
            }),

            // // Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
                // Can be `server`, `static` or `disabled`.
                // In `server` mode analyzer will start HTTP server to show bundle report.
                // In `static` mode single HTML file with bundle report will be generated.
                // In `disabled` mode you can use this plugin to just generate Webpack Stats JSON file by setting `generateStatsFile` to `true`.
                analyzerMode: 'static',
                // Host that will be used in `server` mode to start HTTP server.
                analyzerHost: '127.0.0.1',
                // Port that will be used in `server` mode to start HTTP server.
                analyzerPort: 8888,
                // Path to bundle report file that will be generated in `static` mode.
                // Relative to bundles output directory.
                reportFilename: root('./report.html'),
                // Module sizes to show in report by default.
                // Should be one of `stat`, `parsed` or `gzip`.
                // See "Definitions" section for more information.
                defaultSizes: 'parsed',
                // Automatically open report in default browser
                openAnalyzer: false,
                // If `true`, Webpack Stats JSON file will be generated in bundles output directory
                generateStatsFile: false,
                // Name of Webpack Stats JSON file that will be generated if `generateStatsFile` is `true`.
                // Relative to bundles output directory.
                statsFilename: 'stats.json',
                // Options for `stats.toJson()` method.
                // For example you can exclude sources of your modules from stats file with `source: false` option.
                // See more options here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-1/lib/Stats.js#L21
                statsOptions: null,
                // Log level. Can be 'info', 'warn', 'error' or 'silent'.
                logLevel: 'info'
            })
        );
    }

    return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```